# Python: Matrix Manipulation for a Panel type data

Tags: python, dataframe

So I am cleaning some panel data using Python, and I am a bit stuck on coding in DataFrame

So, I have a DataFrame (or Matrix)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTSsZ.jpg)

I need some variables for the realization of the event. So it needs to be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbNc.jpg)

I got a couple of differen shape of triangular matrix, but I need a upper-right triangular maxtrix as seen in the above

I have tried a couple of different way of indexing and de-panelize the matrix. But I have no idea how I can proceed further

------ Added -------------------

So I tried a couple of methods. I tried to capture future realization as follows, but then there were two problems: There was some weird overlapping with the next panel, and it exploded the limit of rows.

Also, I tried to take the part out of DataFrame to Array, and tried to transpose or flip, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried ?

Comment: @Saxtheowl I just updated the posting, adding what I have tried to do